# Make 2 ExtJs lib coexist in a project

Tags: extjs

Does anyone know if this is possible ?
Because I don't really see of this could be done. My issue is that there is already an big legacy on my project based on ExtJs 2.x and I would like to push the project towards the use of ExtJs 4, as the framework received major updates and changes through the years.
Now, one major issue with this, is that is If I put references to the 2 libs, their might be (highly probable) functions/components with the same name/functions, which will probably mess everything.

Has anyone been confronted with this kind of issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ext 4 now supports sandboxing the framework, meaning you can rename the "Ext" namespace to something else like "Ext4" during the build (that's the global name used in ext-all-sandbox.js). That way even components with the same name will all live under separate top-level namespaces and should be able to run together (though I've never tried this against Ext 2.x, so YMMV).

See the official [sandbox example](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/sandbox/sandbox.html) which loads both Ext 3 and 4 on the same page. It uses the 3.x desktop example but also includes a charts panel from 4.x.

Comment: Another way was to have different frames with different versions of ext, renamed in them.